mount() method from the DocusignJS library requires Id attribute, but LWC in Salesforce can't have fixed Id values
I am trying to build an embedded signing experience inside a Salesforce Experience Cloud Site from an LWC, and I tried to follow the documentation to build an LWC that can do the same. Here is the relevant LWC code -
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import sendEnvelope from '@salesforce/apex/DocusignEmbeddedSigningController.sendEnvelope';
import getEmbeddedSigningUrl from '@salesforce/apex/DocusignEmbeddedSigningController.getEmbeddedSigningUrl';

import docusignjs from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/docusignjs";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class DocusignEmbeddedSigning extends LightningElement {

    template = '2d749f04-1bdb-4b70-9cef-64ab148c6ba0';
    description = 'Embedded Signing';

    renderedCallbackExecuted = false;

    async renderedCallback() {
        if (this.renderedCallbackExecuted) {
            return;
        }
        this.renderedCallbackExecuted = true;

        await Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, docusignjs)
        ]);

        let envelopeId = await sendEnvelope({template: this.template, description: this.description}); 
        let signingUrl = await getEmbeddedSigningUrl({envId: envelopeId, url: window.location.href});

        let docuSignObj = await window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign();
        
        const signing = docuSignObj.signing({
            url: signingUrl,
            displayFormat: 'focused',
            style: {
                /** High-level variables that mirror our existing branding APIs. Reusing the branding name here for familiarity. */
                branding: {
                    primaryButton: {
                        /** Background color of primary button */
                        backgroundColor: '#333',
                        /** Text color of primary button */
                        color: '#fff',
                    }
                },

                /** High-level components we allow specific overrides for */
                signingNavigationButton: {
                    finishText: 'You have finished the document! Hooray!',
                    position: 'bottom-center'
                }
            }
        });

        signing.on('ready', (event) => {
            console.log('UI is rendered');
        });

        signing.on('sessionEnd', (event) => {
            /** The event here denotes what caused the sessionEnd to trigger, such as signing_complete, ttl_expired etc../ **/
            console.log('sessionend', event);
        });

        signing.mount(this.template.querySelector('.docusign-agreement-container'));
    }
}

The problem is with the sigining.mount() method. As per documentation (https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/15-minutes-to-better-ux-enhancing-embedded-signing-focused-view, and https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/), this method is supposed to receive an Id based selector.
But unfortunately, the LWC framework does not allow developers to provide their values in the ID attribute of HTML elements and will override them with dynamically generated values (which is why I attempted to use this.template.querySelector to use a CSS based selector)
The get the following error with the above approach - [n.template.querySelector is not a function]
I then attempted this - signing.mount('.docusign-agreement-container');, and now the error I get is this in the browser console - [DocuSign JS] Container element not found: ".docusign-agreement-container"
Question - Can the mount() method receive a different argument other than Id attributes? Otherwise, using the DocuSignJS library to embed signing experience within Salesforce Experience Cloud is not possible (or extremely difficult).

what would you like the mount method to take? An element reference? Or a class name (that must resolve to a single element)? Or something else?

A class name is a great choice. Throw an error if the class resolves to more than 1 element, but that's still a LOT better than fixating on ID-based selectors.

I have submitted your enhancement idea as Docusign internal ticket C2A-3702. You can ask your account executive or customer support to add your company name to the ticket.

To anyone who is trying to do something similar, use LWCs in light mode to allow Docusign Library to work. Example below -
JS -
export default class PortalContractPage extends LightningElement {
    static renderMode = "light";

    connectedCallback() {
        window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign()
            .then((docusign) => {
                this.showSpinner = false;
                const signing = docusign.signing({
                    url: signUrl,
                    displayFormat:'default',
                    style: {
                        /** High-level variables that mirror our existing branding APIs. Reusing the branding name here for familiarity. */
                        branding: {
                            primaryButton: {
                                /** Background color of primary button */
                                backgroundColor: '#FA70A8',
                                /** Text color of primary button */
                                color: '#fff',
                            }
                        },

                        /** High-level components we allow specific overrides for */
                        signingNavigationButton: {
                            finishText: 'You have finished the document!',
                            position: 'bottom-center',
                            backgroundColor: '#FA70A8',
                            color: '#fff'

                        }
                    }
                });

           signing.mount(this.querySelector('.docusign-agreement'));
    }

    
}

HTML -
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
    <div class="docusign-agreement"></div>
</template>


The mount() method is part of a specific mean of embedded signing, one we call Focused View (which you found in the blog post).
This method requires that you know the ID of the  element because Docusign is going to need that in order to set up the unique UI of Focused View Embedded Signing.
There's another way to do embedded signing, where Docusign just gives you a URL and you can use this URL anyway you want. You can just have a button that have back-end code that generates this URL and then sends the user to that website (it will later redirect back to your website).
Note that the you can also use the Apex Toolkit, but it does not yet support Focused View, so again, you need to use "regular" embedded signing and not use the Docusign.Js library.

Thanks for the response! As you will see from my codebase, I currently am using Apex toolkit, to generate the signing URL, and looks like the only option would be to redirect the user to the signing URL, and have Docusign come back to us.

Can you please tell me how can I build from there? I have further requirements to read the signed document and have it uploaded to an S3 bucket automatically.

Might want to consider some of the new technologies  from Docusign and build an extension app that does file archive.

https://developers.docusign.com/extension-apps/build-an-extension-app/

https://github.com/docusign/extension-app-file-archive-reference-implementation

You can build an app that uploads (archives) to an S3 bucket

Perhaps add the focused view signing ceremony inside of an LWC iframe component? See https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-build-a-reusable-iframe-with-lightning-web-components-76a2ad27286

Thanks for the response! I have already tried rendering the DocuSign signing URL in an iFrame, and that is a very bad user experience, as DocuSign will reload the entire iFrame once the user is done signing.

if you're using docusign.js, your enclosing page can catch the SessionComplete event, then send a message to the parent page to close the iframe.

iFrames have their own concerns and do need in depth testing. Please read here for issues with iFrames https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-problems-iframes
If you do want to go ahead with iFrames, then here are steps to allow a redirect in Experience Cloud for Docusign (avoiding the window within a window).

Create a Visualforce page, called for example "docusignRedirect.vfp", with this code:



<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"
    applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" showQuickActionVfHeader="false">

<html>
    

    <body onload="redirect()">
        <script>   
            function redirect(){
                window.top.location.href = '[redirect url]';
            }                    
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>




in Experience Cloud Site "Builder", add a new Theme, call it "NoHeader" (untick "Show header"):


Create a new page, call it "redirect". Add the visualforce page "DocusignRedirect" into the body:




Apply the custom "NoHeader" them to this page:


Now you have a redirect url that you can place into the Apex controller. eg: 'https://example.my.site.com/s/redirect'. Code example below




global static String getEmbeddedSigningURL(final String envelopeId, final Id sourceObjectId) {
            
        String myReturnUrl='https://example.my.site.com/s/redirect'; //REPLACE WITH YOUR REDIRECT SITE
         Url mySigningUrl = dfsle.SigningService.getEmbeddedSigningUrl(
                                dfsle.UUID.parse(envelopeId), // DocuSign envelope ID
                                new Url(myReturnUrl)); // Where to redirect the user upon signing completion.        
        return mySigningUrl.ToExternalForm();                           
    }



